# Is there a wrapper to write async-await functions without using try-catch blocks

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

I tried using express-async-handler, express-async-errors modules, but it only handles throw errors, doesn't handle reject error thrown by isString function below

```
router.patch('/updateAddress', checkSession, isValidUser, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { user_id } = req.body;
        let address= (req.body.address);
        await isString({ address},20);
        let query = "UPDATE user_table SET email= ? WHERE user_id = ?";
        await sqlQuery(query, [email, user_id]);
        return res.status(200).send(generateResponse(1, `email updated to : ${email}`, []));
    }
    catch (e) {
        return res.status(400).send(generateResponse(0, e.err, []));
    }
})
```

functions if needed for reference

```
const isString=(val, minlen = 1, maxlen)=> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let name = Object.keys(val)[0];
    let str = val[name];
        if(xss(str) !== str) {
            return reject({err: `${name} is an unacceptable string`});
        }
        if (typeof str !== "string") {
      return reject({ err: `${name} is not string` });
    }
    if (minlen !== undefined && str.length < minlen) {
      return reject({ err: `${name} is shorter than ${minlen}` });
    }
    if (maxlen !== undefined && str.length > maxlen) {
      return reject({ err: `${name} is larger than ${maxlen}` });
    }
    return resolve(true);
  });
}
```

Comment: `doesn't handle reject error` - it should, why do you think it doesn't? Does `isString` return a Promise? From the name of the function, it would be surprising if it did

Comment: yes isString returns promise...it looks like this, not exact function though `const isString=(val, minlen = 1, maxlen)=> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (typeof str !== "string") {
      return reject({ err: "${name} is not string" });
    }
}`

Comment: Although I don't see why you're wrapping the `isString`-validation in a promise, the `catch` block should definitely catch it. What does `generateResponse` do?

Comment: Could you provide an exact one? This one looks incorrect.

Comment: just formats the response `generateResponse : function(status, message, data){
    return {
      status,
      message,
      data
    }
  }`

Comment: it does look odd that you're promisfying a syncrhonous method - regardless, your try/catch should  be working